# Nesting filename in composer without file extension

Tags: qgis, expression, dynamic-text

I just want to supress the file extension (.qgs) on my file name: `srv1245_d005.qgs`.

`[% substr(@project_filename ,1,12)%]` works although sometimes our filename will be 13 characters long or more so to supress the extension only would be the ideal solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For QGIS 2.x**:

```
[%replace( @project_filename , '.qgs', '')%]
```

---

**For QGIS 3.x**

```
[% @project_basename %]
```

Comment: amazing- thank you! :)

Comment: @Ruby feel free to [accept an answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) if you think it solves your question appropriately.